# maps,filter,folds and more? Do we really need these in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Maps, filters, folds and more : http://learnyousomeerlang.com/higher-order-functions#maps-filters-folds

The more I read ,the more i get confused.

Can any body help ***simplify*** these concepts?

I am not able to understand the significance of these concepts.In what ***use cases*** will these be needed?

I think it is majorly because of the syntax,diff to find the flow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concepts of mapping, filtering and folding prevalent in functional programming actually are simplifications - or stereotypes - of different operations you perform on collections of data.  In imperative languages you usually do these operations with loops.

Let's take `map` for an example.  These three loops all take a sequence of elements and return a sequence of squares of the elements:

```
// C - a lot of bookkeeping
int data[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int squares_1_to_5[sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0])];
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]); ++i)
    squares_1_to_5[i] = data[i] * data[i];

// C++11 - less bookkeeping, still not obvious
std::vec<int> data{1,2,3,4,5};
std::vec<int> squares_1_to_5;
for (auto i = begin(data); i < end(data); i++)
    squares_1_to_5.push_back((*i) * (*i));

// Python - quite readable, though still not obvious
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
squares_1_to_5 = []
for x in data:
    squares_1_to_5.append(x * x)
```

The property of a `map` is that it takes a collection of elements and returns the same number of somehow modified elements.  No more, no less. Is it obvious at first sight in the above snippets?  No, at least not until we read loop bodies. What if there were some `if`s inside the loops?  Let's take the last example and modify it a bit:

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
squares_1_to_5 = []
for x in data:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        squares_1_to_5.append(x * x)
```

This is no longer a `map`, though it's not obvious before reading the body of the loop.  It's not clearly visible that the resulting collection might have less elements (maybe none?) than the input collection.

We `filter`ed the input collection, performing the action only on some elements from the input.  This loop is actually a `map` combined with a `filter`.

Tackling this in C would be even more noisy due to allocation details (how much space to allocate for the output array?) - the core idea of the operation on data would be drowned in all the bookkeeping.

A `fold` is the most generic one, where the result doesn't have to contain any of the input elements, but somehow depends on (possibly only some of) them.

Let's rewrite the first Python loop in Erlang:

```
lists:map(fun (E) -> E * E end, [1,2,3,4,5]).
```

It's explicit. We see a map, so we know that this call will return a list as long as the input.
And the second one:

```
lists:map(fun (E) -> E * E end,
          lists:filter(fun (E) when E rem 2 == 0 -> true;
                           (_) -> false end,
                       [1,2,3,4,5])).
```

Again, `filter` will return a list at most as long as the input, `map` will modify each element in some way.

The latter of the Erlang examples also shows another useful property - the ability to compose `map`s, `filter`s and `fold`s to express more complicated data transformations. It's not possible with imperative loops.

Answer (score 2):

They are used in almost *every* application, because they abstract different kinds of iteration over lists.

`map` is used to transform one list into another. Lets say, you have list of key value tuples and you want just the keys. You could write:

```
keys([]) -> [];
keys([{Key, _Value} | T]) ->
    [Key | keys(T)].
```

Then you want to have values:

```
values([]) -> [];
values([{_Key, Value} | T}]) ->
    [Value | values(T)].
```

Or list of only third element of tuple:

```
third([]) -> [];
third([{_First, _Second, Third} | T]) ->
    [Third | third(T)].
```

Can you see the pattern? The only difference is what you take from the element, so instead of repeating the code, you can simply write what you do for one element and use `map`.

```
Third = fun({_First, _Second, Third}) -> Third end,
map(Third, List).
```

This is much shorter and the shorter your code is, the less bugs it has. Simple as that.
You don't have to think about corner cases (what if the list is empty?) and for experienced developer it is much easier to read.

`filter` searches lists. You give it function, that takes element, if it returns `true`, the element will be on the returned list, if it returns `false`, the element will not be there. For example filter logged in users from list.

`foldl` and `foldr` are used, when you have to do additional bookkeeping while iterating over the list - for example summing all the elements or counting something.

The best explanations, I've found about those functions are in books about Lisp: ["Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs"](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#%_sec_1.3) and ["On Lisp" Chapter 4.](http://ep.yimg.com/ty/cdn/paulgraham/onlisp.pdf).